# GLFW setUserPointer / getUserPointer sending / accessing class crash

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

When I try to send and access a class with glfwSetUserPointer / glfwGetUserPointer I print random values and the app crashes. I can send a struct in the same way successfully, but I want to send a class instead so I don't have to manage multiple things. I assume the static_cast isn't not working and if so what is a replacement? The callback includes the Test class declaration.

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test() { ; }

    string aString;
};

GLFWwindow *GLFWwin;
GLFWwin = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "myProj", 0, 0);

auto myTest = new Test();
myTest->aString = "str";
cout << "myTest->aString = " << myTest->aString << endl; //prints "str"

glfwSetWindowUserPointer(GLFWwin, &myTest);
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(GLFWwin, myCursorPosCallback);

do
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glfwSwapBuffers(GLFWwin);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

while (glfwWindowShouldClose(GLFWwin) == 0);


void myCursorPosCallback(GLFWwindow *GLFWwin, double xPos, double yPos)
{
    auto *myTest = static_cast<Test*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(GLFWwin));
    cout << "myTest->aString = " << myTest->aString << endl; //prints random vals then crash
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **not** passing the address of the `Test()` object you created as the window user pointer:

```
auto myTest = new Test();
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(GLFWwin, &myTest);
```

`myTest` is of type `Test*`, and you are taking the *address of the pointer* here, which means `&myTest` is of type `Test**`. The `myTest` pointer itself is a local variable and will become invalid as soon as it gets out of scope. In practice, that means that you passed a pointer to *some random location on your stack* to `glfwSetWindowUserPointer`, and when you later retrieve it back and dereference it, you get undefined behavior.

Just pass the ponter to your object:

```
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(GLFWwin, myTest);
```